# Read the value of DictionaryEntry object if the value is List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, collections

I want to parse my `Hashtable` using `DictionaryEntry` and read the value of `DictionaryEntry` object if the value is `List<string>`
Below is the sample code.

```
Hashtable strResx = new Hashtable();
List<string> allDetails = new List<string>();
allDetails.Add("val0");
allDetails.Add("val1");
strResx.Add(1, allDetails);
strResx.Add(2, allDetails);
strResx.Add(3, allDetails);
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in strResx) 
{
string value0 = entry.Value.ToString();
string value1 = entry.Value.ToString();
someFunction(value0, , value1);
}
```

I am really confused how to do indexing to `entry.Value.ToString();`
something like `entry.Value[0].ToString();` and `entry.Value[1].ToString();`

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast value to `List<string>` type:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in strResx)
{
    var value = (List<string>)entry.Value;
    string value0 = value[0];
    string value1 = value[1];
    someFunction(value0, value1);
}
```

You can do this cast automatically in foreach loop if you'll loop through `Values` insted of entries:

```
foreach (List<string> value in strResx.Values)
{    
    string value0 = value[0];
    string value1 = value[1];
    someFunction(value0, value1);
}
```

But consider to use generic `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` instead of `Hashtable`. That will give you both type-safety (i.e. there will not be dictionary entry with value of type different from `List<string>`) and strongly-typed keys and values:

```
var strResx = new Dictionary<int,List<string>>();
// ...
strResx.Add(1, allDetails);
strResx.Add(2, allDetails);
strResx.Add(3, allDetails);

foreach (var kvp in strResx)
{    
    string value0 = kvp.Value[0];
    string value1 = kvp.Value[1];
    someFunction(value0, value1);    
}
```

Notes:

- You are adding same `allDetails` list to all hashtable entries
- Consider to check whether entry value is not null
- Consider to check whether entry value has enough items to avoid `IndexOutOfRange` exception

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use something like:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in strResx)
{
    var list = (List<string>)entry.Value;
    string value0 = list[0];
    string value1 = list[1];
    someFunction(value0, value1);
}
```